# How to updated the contents of the memory in the particular location?

Tags: python-3.6, ctypes, mmap, memoryview

I am trying to read/write and update the contents of the memory by using python.
I found that there are many ways to go on like  mmap,memoryview,id() and ctypes.
I chose the ctype library, By using this, I can get the address but i don't how to updated the values in a particular location of the memory. Unfortunately, i didn't write the proper code by now.
That's why i didn't share.
Can someone guide me regarding this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ctypes` buffer for a range of virtual memory using `from_address`.

Here's an example of something not normally possible.  It takes an immutable string, and modifies it using a ctypes buffer:

```py
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> import sys
>>> s = 'xxxx'
>>> sys.getsizeof(s) # The size of the PyObject s represents
53
>>> id(s)  # The address of the PyObject (implementation detail of CPython!)
2092123519664
>>> b=(c_char * sys.getsizeof(s)).from_address(id(s)) # A writeable ctypes buffer
>>> b.raw  # Note xxxx in the last few bytes of the buffer.
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\xae7\x88\xfc\x7f\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x91\xb1\xe4,\xe4\x8d</\xe5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xxxx\x00'
>>> b[-2]=ord('y')  # reassign the last 'x'
>>> s               # changed the "immutable" string.
'xxxy'
```

So use the pattern `(c_char * size).from_address(address)` to make a window into virtual memory that you can read/write.